# HTML SMS link. Phone doesn't recognize % symbol in message body?

Tags: html, sms, href, urlencode, percentage

My link looks like this:

```
<a href="sms:0038765224488?body=I wanna use coupon to buy with -50&#37; off regular price"> ORDER VIA SMS </a>
```

But percentage sign does not show on my phone when i try to order it.
Screenshot:

[image]

Also, my content encoding is set to UTF-8.

Any solution?

---

**EDIT:** OK, here's a solution, which worked for me:

```
<a href="sms:0038765224488?body=I wanna use coupon to buy with -50%2525; off regular price"> ORDER VIA SMS </a>
```

So, obviously, it somehow got encoded twice since getting to my phone's message body. And since %25 is code for percent symbol, %2525 encodes twice leaving just % in the end. It works like a charm now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Because you are not encoding your url

Comment: I tried "buy with -50%25 off" too, but my phone shown messaging as non-responding and closed it. Any idea where i made mistake?

Comment: all message should be URL encoded, notice there is a space between -50 and the '%' symbol, spaces are represented as %20 so the whole thin should look like this: -50 %   --- > -50%20%